# How to Get Field Name Given Value in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets say I have the following in my Colours index:

```
{
     "primary_colours": ["Red", "Yellow", "Blue"],
     "secondary_colours": ["Green", "Orange", "Purple"],
     "complex_colours": ["Amber", "Apricot", "Aqua", "Olive"]
}
```

What I'd like to achieve is find the field name by searching in all fields. In other words: Given a query, I do NOT know in which field the query should be found.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/colours/_search?pretty' -d '
     {"query": 
          {"match": {"_all": "Aqua"} } 
     }'
```

In the _source section of the hits, I would like elasticsearch to tell me that which field had the value and not just return me the entire document.

Any help in figuring this out will be appreciated.

Comment: probably you could use  [highlighting](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) as a workaround ?

Comment: @keety Thanks so much for your comment Highlighting works !!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your documents are structured well for your query. It's hard to suggest a better structure without knowing what other queries you're going to need to use, but it sounds like the "color type" can be a [bucketed aggregation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html). With this you can have each color indexed with a facet saying which type of color you'd want to look up. Like I said it's difficult to know what structure would work best without knowing more about the queries you're hoping to run.

Comment: keety's comment above resolved the issue. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question.